# Xamarin iOS Linker Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-linker

I have an application that has an android and ios project with shared code. The android application works perfectly and uses the SDK Only linker. I also have a Linker file to enforce linker not removing used functions - Which is a fairly large file and I've also tried adding a bunch of preserve attributes. The same situation in the iOS project, however, doing the same thing doesn't work. It removes something from EF and throws this exception:

```
"The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException"
```

This whole codebase works perfectly fine without the linking. I've added a bunch of mtouch arguments to try and skip it but that ain't working either.

```
--linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 
--linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 
--linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 
--linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 
--linkskip=Interactive.Async 
--linkskip=Remotion.Linq 
--linkskip=System.Data 
--linkskip=System.Collections.Immutable 
--linkskip=System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 
--linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 
--linkskip=System.Interactive.Async 
--linkskip=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 
--linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 
--linkskip=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 
--linkskip=System.ComponentModel.Annotations
```

I'm about to add every DLL in the NuGet repository which will make the Linker useless. Is this a bug for the iOS Linker or what am I missing here? I've read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows and searched everywhere on the internet and nothing comes up. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using "Link SDK assemblies only" option on iOS project, then all of those `--linkskip` arguments won't do anything as only the SDK assemblies are being linked. So the `EntityFrameworkCore` might be using something that is being linked away that is in the Xamarin.iOS SDK assemblies. `System.Linq` is part of the SDK and adds extension methods for many database types.

So I think you may be hitting this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3394

If so, try putting:

```
[assembly: Preserve (typeof (System.Linq.Queryable), AllMembers = true)]
```

in the Main.cs file of the iOS project outside of the namespace, e.g.:

```
using UIKit;

[assembly: Preserve (typeof (System.Linq.Queryable), AllMembers = true)]
namespace
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If this does not work maybe check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405590/error-using-entityframework-core-with-sqlite-in-xamarin-ios).