# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ResultOperators.Internal.TrackingExpressionNode' threw an exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am building xamarin forms app, I am using the package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" in my project,

when I run the app on ios/ipad I get following error:

`The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ResultOperators.Internal.TrackingExpressionNode' threw an exception`

on android it works fine

Answer (score 5):

That is most likely related to the linker removing assemblies that are only accessed through reflection. Putting `[assembly: Preserve (typeof (System.Linq.Queryable), AllMembers = true)]` in your Main.cs file (above the namespace) in your iOS project should fix it. You can find some more info on this behavior in the links from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574016/7183682.